# Could not find this LEGO brick, any ideas?

Tags: part-identification

Could you identify this LEGO brick? No ID number found on it...

Many thanks!

[image: Unknown brick]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [Legs without Split](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15&idColor=11#T=C&C=11), which were used for the very first LEGO minifigures.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick and on point